# Filtering on multiple fields in an Elasticsearch ObjectField()

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am having trouble figuring out the filtering syntax for [ObjectFields()](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html) in [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). In particular, when I try to filter on multiple subfields of the same ObjectField(), I'm getting incorrect results.

For example, consider the following document

```py
class ItemDocument(Document):
    product = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'name': fields.TextField(),
        'description': fields.TextField()
    })
    details = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'category_id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'value': fields.FloatField()
    })
    description = fields.TextField()
```

I want to find an Item with a detail object that has both `category_id == 3` and `value < 1.5`, so I created the following query

```py
x = ItemDocument.search().filter(Q("match",details__category_id=3) & Q("range",details__value={'lt':1.5})).execute()
```

Unfortunately, this returns all items which have a detail object with `category_id==3` and a separate detail object with `value < 1.5` e.g.

```json
{
  "product": ...
  "details": [
    {
      "category_id": 3,
      "id": 7,
      "value": 20.0
    },
    {
      "category_id": 4,
      "id": 7,
      "value": 1.0
    },
    ...
]
}
```

instead of my desired result of all items that have a detail object with both `category_id==3` AND `value < 1.5` e.g.

```json
{
  "product": ...
  "details": [
    {
      "category_id": 3,
      "id": 7,
      "value": 1.0
    },
    ...
]
}
```

How do I properly format this query using django-elasticsearch-dsl?